# bash expanding to same value instead of line by line value in sed command

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, sed

I have a file containing numbers in it say numbers.txt as follows.

```
9374541632553  
51243747879841  
32030098896914  
84654557358238  
11000656847765
```

I want to convert it to the following format.

```
<item>9 3 7 4 5 4 1 6 3 2 5 5 3 <tag>out="9374541632553" 
<item>5 1 2 4 3 7 4 7 8 7 9 8 4 1 <tag>out="51243747879841" 
<item>3 2 0 3 0 0 9 8 8 9 6 9 1 4 <tag>out="32030098896914"
<item>8 4 6 5 4 5 5 7 3 5 8 2 3 8 <tag>out="84654557358238"
<item>1 1 0 0 0 6 5 6 8 4 7 7 6 5 <tag>out="11000656847765"
```

I'am using following command to convert it.

```
cat numbers.txt | while read line; do sed -r "s/([0-9])/\1/g; s/([0-9])/\1 /g ; s/^/<item>/g; s/$/<tag>out="\$line/g" ; done
```

But output I'am getting is as follows:

```
<item>5 1 2 4 3 7 4 7 8 7 9 8 4 1 <tag>out="9374541632553
<item>3 2 0 3 0 0 9 8 8 9 6 9 1 4 <tag>out="9374541632553
<item>8 4 6 5 4 5 5 7 3 5 8 2 3 8 <tag>out="9374541632553
<item>1 1 0 0 0 6 5 6 8 4 7 7 6 5 <tag>out="9374541632553
<item>3 3 2 1 6 7 8 2 0 9 3 8 4 2 <tag>out="9374541632553
```

Anyone can you please tell me why only 1st line is getting printed at last column instead of line by line value.
And what about 1st line in output?
Explain the required command to desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without loop in `awk`:

```
awk '{a=$1;gsub(/./,"& ",$1); print "<item>"$1"<tag><out>=""\""a"\""}' numbers.txt
```

Output:

```
<item>9 3 7 4 5 4 1 6 3 2 5 5 3 <tag><out>="9374541632553"
<item>5 1 2 4 3 7 4 7 8 7 9 8 4 1 <tag><out>="51243747879841"
<item>3 2 0 3 0 0 9 8 8 9 6 9 1 4 <tag><out>="32030098896914"
<item>8 4 6 5 4 5 5 7 3 5 8 2 3 8 <tag><out>="84654557358238"
<item>1 1 0 0 0 6 5 6 8 4 7 7 6 5 <tag><out>="11000656847765"
```

Explanation:

- first we store first field `$1` in variable `a`
- substitute each character in `$1` with itself followed by space
- and finally print everything in desired order.
- a little tricky part is printing double quotes where `\"` should be quoted itself

Edit (removing last space):

```
awk '{a=$1;gsub(/./,"& ",$1); printf "<item>"$1"\b<tag><out>=""\""a"\"\n"}' numbers.txt

<item>9 3 7 4 5 4 1 6 3 2 5 5 3<tag><out>="9374541632553"
<item>5 1 2 4 3 7 4 7 8 7 9 8 4 1<tag><out>="51243747879841"
<item>3 2 0 3 0 0 9 8 8 9 6 9 1 4<tag><out>="32030098896914"
<item>8 4 6 5 4 5 5 7 3 5 8 2 3 8<tag><out>="84654557358238"
<item>1 1 0 0 0 6 5 6 8 4 7 7 6 5<tag><out>="11000656847765"
```

Comment: can u please explain the above awk command ....I mean how it works

Comment: what if we want to remove space between last number and word '<tag><out>'

Comment: @AVJ see the edit for explanation, to remove last space just use `printf` instead of `print` and hit backspace `\b`.

Answer (score 1):

Because both `read` and `sed` are taking data from stdin.

In the `while` loop, you `read` the first line into `$line`. Then `sed` starts: you don't give it any other input so it reads from stdin, which is the output of `cat numbers.txt`. So `sed` will consume the rest of the input. And since you're still in the first iteration of the while loop, the $line variable doesn't change

I'd use perl for this:

```
perl -lne '($spaced = $_) =~ s/./$& /g; print qq{<item>$spaced<tag>out="$_"}' numbers.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation.. it helped me to understand...Also by your command i can achieve desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might be able to do the whole thing in sed:

```
sed '
    h; 
    s/./& /g;
    s/.*/<item>&<tag>out=/;
    G;
    s/\n\([0-9]*\)/"\1"/;
    ' numbers.txt
```

Comment: Removing regexp speed up script more then 25% `h; s/./& /g; s/^/<item>/; G; s/\n\(.*\)/<tag>out="\1"/`

Answer (score 1):

I would think the quickest way to do it would look something like...

```
sed -e's/./& /g;i\' -e'<item>' \
    -ea\\ -e'<tag><out>=' <file |
paste -d'\0 ""' - - - ./file /dev/null
```

This also works:

```sh
(       set -- - - - - - - /tmp/file
        paste -d'<item> <tag><out>="'  "$@" - - - - - - "$@" |
        sed 's/ *$/"/;s/\([0-9]\) *\(<.*\)*/\1 \2/g'
)       </dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this...

```
cat numbers.txt | while read line; do echo $line | sed -r "s/([0-9])/\1/g; s/([0-9])/\1 /g ; s/^/<item>/g; s/$/<tag>out=\"$line\"/g" ; done
```

Or,

```
cat numbers.txt | while read line; do echo "<item>$(echo $line | fold -w1 | paste -s -d' ') <tag>out=\"$line\""; done
```